# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Gaussian random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, random-matrices, eigenvalues

Let us assume we have a square matrix $A$ whose entries are sampled from a standard Gaussian distribution of mean $0$. Do we have any information about the distribution of its eigenvalues?

Particularly, I'm aware that there are different results on symmetric gaussian matrices (or, the Gaussian orthogonal ensemble of $A$):

- The eigenvalues follow a semicircle law

Is there an equivalent result for standard, non-symmetric Gaussian matrices?

Comment: I have answered this for the ensemble of nonsymmetric matrices, but do note that your statements on the symmetric case (GOE) are not correct: the eigenvalues follow a [semicircle law](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html), not a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the answer, I'll edit for future readers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the Ginibre ensemble, see [Eigenvalue statistics of the real Ginibre ensemble](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2020) for the eigenvalue distribution. For an $N\times N$ matrix with $N\gg 1$ there are on average $\sqrt{2N/\pi}$ eigenvalues on the real axis, uniformly in the interval $(-\sqrt N,\sqrt N$). The rest of the eigenvalues fill a disc of radius $\sqrt N$ in the complex plane, uniformly except for a depleted strip along the real axis. Here is a scatter plot of the eigenvalues for $N=100$ (taken from [arXiv:1305.2924](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2924)).

[image]